Severe slowdown when using dataset logging (autologging) with lightgbm in mlflow
I'm experiencing severe slowdowns (10-50x the usual time) when tracking the dataset during training runs with mlflow.
The code looks something like this:
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://localhost:5000")
mlflow.set_experiment("My Experiment")

mlflow.lightgbm.autolog()
train, val = get_datasets() # returns lightgbm.Dataset objects
train_model(train, val) # calls lightgbm.train

When disabling the tracking of the dataset, by setting mlflow.lightgbm.autolog(log_datasets=False) , I experience no noticeable slowdowns.
Any ideas why this is the case?
I would expect no noticable slowdowns since mlflow only tracks some basic stats of the dataset (or at least it seems that way. The ui and the documentation do not suggest otherwise)
